# use if else statement in python selenium for a text_to_be_present_in_element

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I have following line of code which after uploading files returns 'Upload successful!' text . But several times there is error in uploading files and the element of website displays 'Upload Status' in place of 'Upload Successful'. So how to use the logic of if else statment to run the the rest command even if it failed to upload and continue with next file. I did following but dosen't work

```py
if WebDriverWait(driver, 300, 1).until(
    EC.text_to_be_present_in_element((By.XPATH, "//*"), "Upload successful!")
):
    print("uploaded")
    driver.back()
else:
    print("upload failed")
    driver.back()
```

```
 OR
```

```py
myStr = WebDriverWait(driver, 300, 1).until(
    EC.text_to_be_present_in_element((By.XPATH, "//*"))
)

if myStr.txt.contains("Upload successful!"):
    print("uploaded")
    driver.back()
else:
    print("upload failed")
    driver.back()
```

How to do this?

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean? I don't know the Selenium API, but at the very least, the second snippet doesn't look like valid Python code. Further, neither is a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @ndc85430 yeah sure the bottom snippet is not python code. But that is just an logic i want to use but i don't know how to apply if else condition in selenium text_to_be_present_in_element method so that if upload successful present do this else do that.